# Debian : Installing Coturn causing error, and package not getting removed.

Tags: linux, debian, command-line, package-management

I am working on install [Coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn/blob/master/INSTALL) which is an open-source Stun and TURN server. For that, I had two options, one was to download the debian package and install it by gdebi, and other was to make the project manually. I went for the easier route, and unfortunately the package installation is failing.

Right now, even when I try to remove the package it fails : Is there any way I can remove this package and install it properly either via source or binary.

Output for purge :

```
coturn-master # apt-get purge coturn
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  coturn
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 539 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 1.234 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 51439 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing coturn ...
update-rc.d: error: cannot find a LSB script for coturn
dpkg: error processing coturn (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 coturn
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have the source package downloaded for coturn, but I cannot use that as dependencies are not satisfied, and whenver I try to manually fulfil the dependencies, coturn throws stones in path.. :-(

```
coturn-master # ./configure
ginstall: not found
install is /usr/bin/install
pkill is /usr/bin/pkill
sqlite3: not found
sqlite: not found
Use TMP dir /var/tmp
Compiler: cc
Library option -lsocket cannot be used
Library option -lwldap32 cannot be used
Library option -lwldap64 cannot be used
Library option -lintl cannot be used
Sockets code is fine: no sin_len field present
Ignore IP_RECVERR
Crypto SSL lib found.
SSL lib found.
Libevent2 development is not installed properly
ERROR: Libevent2 development libraries are not installed properly in required location.
ERROR: may be you have just too old libevent tool - then you have to upgrade it.
See the INSTALL file.
Abort.


coturn-master # apt-get install sqlite3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc-l10n libc6 libc6-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev locales oracle-java8-installer postgresql-9.1
  postgresql-9.4 postgresql-contrib-9.4
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc sqlite3-doc binfmt-support visualvm ttf-baekmuk ttf-unfonts ttf-unfonts-core ttf-kochi-gothic ttf-sazanami-gothic
  ttf-kochi-mincho ttf-sazanami-mincho ttf-arphic-uming firefox firefox-2 iceweasel mozilla-firefox iceape-browser
  mozilla-browser epiphany-gecko epiphany-webkit epiphany-browser galeon midbrowser moblin-web-browser xulrunner xulrunner-1.9
  konqueror chromium-browser midori google-chrome locales-all libdbd-pg-perl
Recommended packages:
  postgresql-contrib-9.1 sysstat
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  coturn
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc-l10n sqlite3
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev locales oracle-java8-installer postgresql-9.1 postgresql-9.4
  postgresql-contrib-9.4
11 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 1 to remove and 528 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/19,3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 6.894 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 51439 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing coturn ...
update-rc.d: error: cannot find a LSB script for coturn
dpkg: error processing coturn (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 coturn
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Coturn requires SID branch, so I added this in `source.list`. Is that the reason it's trying to pull PostgreSQL-9.1. I don't want 9.1, I have 9.4 already.

sources.list :

```
deb     http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages wheezy main contrib non-free
deb     http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/security wheezy/updates main contrib non-free

deb     http://cdn.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main non-free contrib
deb-src http://cdn.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main non-free contrib

deb     http://security.debian.org/  wheezy/updates  main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/  wheezy/updates  main contrib non-free
// Below line I added. 
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid main
```

What can I do to remedy this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to upgrade to Debian 8 (Jessie)?

Comment: @StephenKitt : It's our test-server. I wouldn't mind, but last time I tried to upgrade Debian, it nuked the entire OS, the admin had to reinstall. Tell me, will upgrading help with solving coturn installation?

Comment: It should help, yes: Jessie includes [coturn in the distribution](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/coturn), and [version 4.5.0.2](https://packages.debian.org/source/jessie-backports/coturn) is available in [Jessie backports](http://backports.debian.org/). Could you [edit] your question to include the contents of `/var/lib/dpkg/info/coturn.prerm`?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this problem by following commands :

```
mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/coturn.* /tmp/
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq coturn
```

This worked. And I installed coturn again, then it worked.

Comment: @AlexanderBatischev : SO says I can only accept my own answer in 2 days... Will do that then. Thank you. :-)